# Copying one array into another

Tags: vba, excel

My Sub keeps on getting errors on line on line ending with "<--- HERE".

If specify in Dim that array is Full_Path(2) I get `compile error Cannot be assigned to an array`.

If i leave array as dynamic( like in sample bellow), I get `Run-Time error '13': Type mismatch`.

I don't understand why neither would be working?

Also as an input`Entered_Path = D:\Data\MBS`

```
Sub Set_Folder(Entered_Path As String)
    ' this function wil point to the folder that you want your data be saved into
    Dim Drive As String, Folder As String
    Dim Full_Path()

    'Assign this to a Public Variable
    Path = Entered_Path

    Full_Path = Split(Entered_Path, ":", , vbTextCompare)   <--- HERE
    Drive = Full_Path(0)
    Folder = Full_Path(1)

    ChDrive Drive
    ChDir Folder
End Sub
```

Comment: @RossC This only works for VB.NET, this question is about VBA. [Split() Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278528(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: @i_saw_drones ah I didn't realise that, I had a similar split working in VBA but you're right. I've given the more generic version in my answer. But http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-split-function/ this would suggest it's ok..?

Comment: @RossC There seems to be quite a few examples of `CompareMethod.Binary` being used in VBA on the net. Unless you have an enum called `CompareMethod` in your code, it should not work. I would love to see a counterexample though! :)

Comment: @i_saw_drones you're looking at the wrong guy! :) I'm far, far from knowledgeable on this and would definitely bow to your own on this one! I have a mate who'd love that challenge though, just because he's like that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably don't need all those variables.

Look up [Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278528(v=office.15).aspx)

```
Sub SetFolder(Entered_Path)
    ChDrive Split(Entered_Path, ":")(0)
    ChDir Split(Entered_Path, ":")(1)
End Sub
```

That's obviously assuming your path is always in the following format `DRIVE:\FOLDER\SUB`

Comment: +1 far more elegant in this case! For a convoluted version see my answer!

Answer (score 4):

I believe the error is caused because of array declaration

**You have few options**

1. Change `Dim Full_Path()` to either `Dim Full_Path` or `Dim Full_Path() as String`***(Recommended)***
2. Remove the statement `Dim Full_Path()` all together
3. Declare `Dim Full_Path()` as `Dim Full_Path(2) as String`

   In this case, You have to loop through array or grab array by index to place the content

   e.g. `Full_Path(0) = Split(Entered_Path, ":", , vbTextCompare)(0)`

Comment: ++ for actually pointing the error. you can't dimension arrays without providing the size. "Dynamic" version would be a variant array `Full_Path` which will adopt to whatever is put in it by code. The `Full_Path()` needs a size at the stage of `Dim`ing it

Comment: @Rory Ok, you can't **use** it? unless you actually assign another array of the same type to it?

Comment: You declare a dynamic array without dimensions `Dim someArray()` then you can either assign an array of the same type to it in one pass, or resize with `ReDim` (in which case you don't actually require the original `Dim` statement) and populate like any other array.

Answer (score 4):

Split returns a String array so to assign the returned array to a dynamic array they have to be the same type:

```
Dim Full_Path() As String
```

Answer (score 3):

According to Microsoft on the [Split function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx)  you could use a compare method IF REQUIRED. In this case a basic split would probably suffice.

```
Optional ByVal Compare As CompareMethod = CompareMethod.Binary
```

for a binary comparison, or

```
Optional ByVal Compare As CompareMethod = CompareMethod.Textual
```

for textual and then use split:

```
Split(EnteredPaty, ":", ,CompareMethod.Text)
```

You will have an array of {Lastname, Firstname} so you can just have `namesArray(0) & " " & namesArray(1)` to give you Lastname Firstname

Split function at its basic form:

```
Split(Entered_Path, ":")
```

[There is a lot of good reading here with further detail](http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-split-function/)

Answer (score 0):

Changed vbTextcompare to CompareMethod.Text and Full_Path as string array

```
Sub Set_Folder(Entered_Path As String)
'this function wil point to the folder that you want your data be saved into
    Dim Drive As String, Folder As String
    'Dim Full_Path()  <--- Look HERE

    'Assign this to a Public Variable
    Path = Entered_Path

    Dim Full_Path As String() = Split(Entered_Path, ":")   
    <--- Look ABOVE

    Drive = Full_Path(0)
    Folder = Full_Path(1)

    ChDrive Drive
    ChDir Folder
End Sub
```

Comment: `CompareMethod.Text` does not exist in VBA, only in VB.NET [Split() Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278528(v=office.15).aspx).